# Sass failing to compile - Web Essentials 2013 Update 4

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sass, web-essentials

I'm currently using Web Essentials 2013 update 4 to provide support for compiling .scss files in Visual Studio.

The tool has worked fine for me in the past however I have just created a new .scss file and have copied the bootstrap un-minified css into this new file.

Upon saving, the compilation window on the right hand side of the screen fails to update or display the compiled css or any error messages. Meanwhile, the blue bar at the bottom of my Visual Studio screen is stuck on

> Compiling 0 dependent file for bootstrap.scss

[image: Failure to compile]

Usually I would expect a bootstrap.css file to be generated from this as well as a bootstrap.min.css file but this is not happening.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can restore this back to normal working conditions?

[image: No minified file]

Comment: what are those green ticks? Have [you implemented Git's source control in VS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34201058/2404470)? If, yes how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was to do with the settings I had in my WebEssentials-Settings.json file. In version 3, the 'UseRubyRuntime' parameter needed to be marked as true to allow it to auto compile into the relevant files. Since version 4 this can be marked as false as WE now has a built in compiler which I believe may have been conflicting with the RubyRuntime version I was trying to use.

Comment: Setting UseRubyRuntime to "true" seems to have fixed that problem, which uses Ruby Sass instead of Libsass.  I wonder what the underlying issue is with the Libsass version.

Comment: Thank you for answer @jezzipin

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, after installing Web Essentials 2013 Update 4 the .scss files started throwing errors like this to the output:

```
Something went wrong reaching: ... 
SCSS: Site.scss compilation failed: The service failed to respond to this request
Possible cause: Syntax Error!
```

The only solution for me was this:

> 1. Uninstall Web Essentials
> 2. Delete %AppData%\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
> 3. Delete %AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
> 4. Repair VS 2013.4
> 5. Reinstall Web Essentials
>
> Source: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361/view/Discussions/1#15143

And a heads-up: If you import other .scss files, make sure they are in the correct location. When I updated Twitter.Bootstrap.Sass 3.3.3 via NuGet, the related .scss files were moved to a different folder and I had to update references. For example:

Before:

```
@import "../sass/bootstrap/_utilities.scss";
```

After:

```
@import "../stylesheets/bootstrap/_utilities.scss";
```

Comment: I started to do this, and realized that nodejs.exe was hung up. Turns out there was an issue one time compiling my sass and it hung it. Restart machine probably would of fixed it. Or manually stopping the process.

Comment: Simply ending the nodejs.exe processes worked for me, in case anyone else encounters this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and spent some time uninstalling and re-installing Web Essentials.  I tried deleting the parts of AppData that seemed to be related to Web Essential, all with no success at compiling the scss file.

So I created a new .scss with minimal content, that compiled.  Then I started copying over pieces from the failing one.  After a couple of copies, the new one failed too. I was able to zero in on the failure.
It was caused by this line:

> $highlightcolor: #67a0f;

Do you see the problem?  the hex color code is missing a digit. it should have been 67a0f5.  Fixing this fixed the problem with the original file.

I had gone over the file looking for syntax errors, but didn't spot the short color def.

I hope this saves someone some time and frustration.

Comment: While any number of parse errors can cause a "my thing failed to compile", this doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem; in order to help diagnose it I created a minimal .scss file with dummy CSS rules - it generated the same error.

Then I went to my long-time tested and fully working legacy .scss file - it generated the same error. Something is wrong here, I thought.

After tinkering with the issue for a while, somehow it got fixed by closing Visual Studio, reloading and reopening the solution.

Comment: Closing/reopening VS helped me when I couldn't compile due to '`node` not recognized...' message on SCSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the changelog, as of 2.5 for update 4 of Web Essentials:

> - Removed all node.js based tools ◦Sass/LESS compilers 
>     JSHint/JSCS
>     linters CSS AutoPrefixer Handlebars compiler SweetJS/LiveScript
>     compilers

http://vswebessentials.com/changelog

So my understanding is, that it no longer compiles.

Comment: [According to the developer](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/1716#issuecomment-69952105), it looks like that note in the changelog only applies to the 2015 edition of Web Essentials and doesn't affect WE 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem and have eliminated actual syntax errors and incorrect path references. I have found two things out about this.

1. This happens when there is a file that only specifies variables and
   has no actual scss or css markup.  This is more of a hack as you
       may have to put unwanted css in a variables file.
2. Turning off Autoprefixer will resolve the issue entirely, but at the cost of not using this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and determined that when I was running a Compile All SASS Files, the plugin was trying to compile files found in the /obj directory of the project which failed, and consequently caused subsequent compilation to fail.  Deleting the /obj directory and restarting VS fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue and turn out to be a reference to a SASS variable before it was declared. There were no warnings or errors. Once I move the reference to the right place it all worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Going off of what others have said about Web Essentials. Looking at the [change log](http://vswebessentials.com/changelog), it states that for [versions 2013 update 4](https://samrueby.com/2015/03/12/visual-studio-extension-to-compile-sass/) and up (meaning version 2015 as well),

> Important! Bundling, minification and compilation of LESS, Sass and
>   CoffeeScript is not longer part of Web Essentials 2015. Install the
>   new extensions Bundler & Minifier and Web Compiler instead. Also, see
>   this list of other web development extensions that might be of
>   interest to you.

I found this neat little extension for visual studio, that compiles the SCSS file(s) on save into a CSS file (along with minification for that file).

You can get it [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2e7b72e0-f6ca-4e5e-9b30-afcc07d801f0?SRC=Home).
The guy that created this extension also talks about the Web Essential issue as well, found [here](https://samrueby.com/2015/03/12/visual-studio-extension-to-compile-sass/).

Comment: I saw this notice as well, but it's misleading - Less/Sass/Scss compilation remains in Web Essentials 2013.4 and 2013.5. http://i.imgur.com/jy5Z3Uc.png