# Unable to compile valid SASS in Visual Studio with Web Essentials

Tags: visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, sass

I have been using scss to style an upcoming project in Visual Studio 2013 which has been working perfectly up until now.
I suddenly found that the SASS would not compile, so I took apart the code to find a stray missing colon or extra bracket but could find nothing, so I removed everything except a simple css declaration:-

```
body{
color:green;
}
```

Nothing else.
The thing will still not compile and Visual Studio still complains of a syntax error.
I'm stuck!
I have the latest Web Essentials installed.

***Edit. June 2015.**

I have returned to this as I had originally believed that I had fixed the problem by removing Web Essentials and then re-installing. It turns out that this was **incorrect**. There is a much simpler solution and I'm kicking myself for not realising it.

If you face this issue yourself. >>**Just restart Visual Studio**<<. It's as simple as that.

Hopefully this saves someone else from frustration.

Comment: What is the error?  Did you try checking with the CSS validator?  Stray characters can cause compilation problems.

Comment: The error is the generic message about a syntax problem - the markup is fine, I pasted it into this online generator http://sassmeister.com/ and it compiles.

Comment: It's not a case of the file extension being wrong. As mentioned it was compiling fine. I just isn't now!

Answer (score -2):

I appear to have found the solution to my issue by following the first answer on this post [Stack Overflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190888/sass-failing-to-compile-web-essentials-2013-update-4) by completely reinstalling Web Essentials. My SASS is compiling again!

Comment: Interesting that I get downvoted for showing how I fixed my issue. Perhaps I should have left it open?

Comment: Sometimes I need to restart VS13 to get sass compiler to work again.

Comment: @Drops I have updated my question with this exact resolution as It's a more simpler solution than the solution I originally had and one I discovered by chance.